# The `top_questions` field shows outdated information?

Tags: support, api-v2, users

I am using Stack Exchange API. I posted question from the doc page [/questions/add](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-question) to Stack Overflow. This was my first question. As that question was to check the function /questions/add, means it was not a proper question to be posted, I deleted it. Now that question is not visible in the Stack Overflow website. But the API is returning it as

```
"top_questions": [
        {
           "score": 0,
           "post_type": "question",
           "post_id": 30978609,
           "title": "Use an access_token with write_access"
        }
     ],
```

as response when [/me/associated](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-associated-users) is ran in doc page. Isn't this a bug?

Also,

```
"question_count": 1,
```

is wrong. It should be 0.

I have done this before in doc page. Question was created. After that, I deleted it because of same reasons. This question doesn't show in API response, which is as expected. In this case API is giving correct response.

And, In Stack Apps, now I have posted 8 questions. But, response is

```
"question_count": 7,
```

and

```
"top_questions": [
        {
           "score": 3,
           "post_type": "question",
           "post_id": 6396,
           "title": "Some blank properties missing"
        },
        {
           "score": 2,
           "post_type": "question",
           "post_id": 6395,
           "title": "Where is &quot;items&quot; &amp; &quot;badge_counts&quot; documentation?"
        },
        {
           "score": 1,
           "post_type": "question",
           "post_id": 6404,
           "title": "How to delete apps in StackApps?"
        },
        {
           "score": 0,
           "post_type": "question",
           "post_id": 6405,
           "title": "Social Connect for Visual Studio (Placeholder)"
        },
        {
           "score": 0,
           "post_type": "question",
           "post_id": 6409,
           "title": "/questions/add of StackExchange app gives nonsense response"
        }
     ],
```

"top_questions" is ambiguous. Can somebody give an explanation on this? Are these bugs?

Answer (score 1):

Although this can be annoying or confusing, there is no bug.
Take a look at [your Stack Exchange accounts page](http://stackexchange.com/users/6482771/amit-jha?tab=accounts).  Currently it shows:

[(Click for larger image)

[image: User's accounts]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5anwb.png)

10 questions, here on Stack Apps, and 1 question on Stack Overflow.
Those are the same [numbers currently reported for you by `/users/{ids}/associated`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users#ids=6482771&filter=!-*f%286r3ZbZjn&run=true).

Both sets of numbers are currently stale (You have 11 and 0 questions), but this is because

## Stack Exchange updates lesser-used reports/statistics in timed jobs.

There is too much data for everything to be instantaneous. That Stack Exchange account information takes anywhere from a few minutes to a day to update, depending on the column.

Also, these [jobs sometimes crash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178114/tag-scores-have-not-updated-script-did-not-run).  So something that normally updates in minutes can *occasionally* take quite a bit longer.

Check back in a day and see if the numbers are still wrong -- assuming you haven't added a bunch more questions. ;)

Comment: But, can you tell about the other problems addressed in the post:
1) I have created two questions from the doc page of [/questions/add](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-question). I deleted both (all) questions. One is still showing in the API as well as [website](http://i.stack.imgur.com/usFe4.png). Other question isn't. I didn't note the question id of the other question which I deleted, that's why I can't show you the snapshot.

Comment: 2) In the [snapshot that you have uploaded](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5anwb.png), it is still showing as showing as one question asked by me in Stack Overflow. But, when you type the question id in browser, you are not able to see it. Also, the question asked doesn't reflect anywhere in [my Stack Overflow profile](http://i.stack.imgur.com/v4X1K.png)

Comment: 3) Why `top_questions` is giving me wrong answer?

Comment: @amitjha, go to [your recently-deleted questions page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/5035500) (which only you can see) and link to a screenshot of that.  I can see your deleted questions, but only if I have the ID. For example, [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hr7yO.png).

Comment: Here is the requested information: [snapshot 1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KPAZZ.png) & [snapshot 2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SLNdu.png)